# Regex find text between tags in files

Tags: html, regex, webstorm

I am trying to find in alley files using a regex search in WebStorm. I have 2 scenarios.

**Scenario 1:** text inside html tag

```
<p>testing</p>
```

**Scenario 2:** dynamic text inside `{{` and `}}` inside html text

```
<p>{{testing}}<p>
```

I was able to find text between html tags using below regex for Scenario 1

```
>(.*?)</
```

I am trying to find only places with scenario 1 and not with scenario 2. I mean I want to see all the hard coded text between html tags and not any text between `{{` and `}}`. Any suggestion or pointer?

Comment: What is the text you would want to get from `<p>testing <em>with emphasis</em> in the text</p>`? (with obligatory link to [warning about regex and html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using regexr.com?

**Edit**
How is this:

```
>(\w+)</
```